# Send data between activities (Checkbox)

Tags: android-activity, send, between

I got an Checkbox and I want that when someone click the checkbox in a other Activity an Text appeared...

I know how to make Listeners with Checkboxes and how to make a Text appear, but my App crashes when I click the CheckBox, so I think I need to make an thing that transfer the information that the CheckBox has been clicked to the other Activity... but *How?*

I tried to make make something with thes putExtras and getExtras, but I didnt found anything that helped!

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

public void doSomethingWhenCheckBoxClicked(View v) {

```
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkBox1:
            if (checked) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("checked", true);
            }

    }
}
```